# Edit and save row data of datatables using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I am working with user role module and display users using datatables with that I have few requirements.

1) when click on edit button make complete row editable and change edit button to save button

2) after editing  data from  editable row  and click on save button(ajax call will update data in db) again it should become edit

3) At a time single row edit and save button  work it should not like click on first  row and without saving changes clicking on every edit button and making every row editable

```
<?php 
$users=$this->db->get('users')->result();?>

<table class="table table-hover" id="catgeory_list">
<tr>
<th>username</th>
<th>role</th>
</tr>
<?php 
foreach($users as $user){?>
<tr>
<td><?=$user->name?></td>
<td class='change_response'<?=$user->id?>><a href="javscript:void(0);" class="edit_role" dataid="<?=$user->id?>"></a></td>
</tr>
<?php}?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   myTable=$('#catgeory_list').DataTable();
}

   $(".edit_role").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("data-dataid");
        alert(id);//
        $(".change_response"+id).html("<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='save_role' dataid='"+id+"'>save</a>");
   //1) make single row editable at a time and change button from edit to save        

    });

    $("body").on('click','.save_role',function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("dataid");
       $(".change_response"+id).html("<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='edit_role' dataid='"+id+"'>Edit</a>"); 
       // ajax call to update data in db

    });
</script>
```